# compare equal to values keeps returning false when true

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to compare a range of numbers, unfortunately it's not allowing me to do <= or >=. Error was about syntax, but I have no idea what's wrong with it. 
So now, I'm left with >, < and comparing equal to separately.

However, what is wrong with my equal to? I also tried addCondition

```
$criteria->compare('add_max_qty ',$this->add_min_qty );
$criteria->compare('add_min_qty ',$this->add_max_qty );

//doesn't work either
$criteria->addCondition('add_max_qty ='.$this->add_min_qty );
$criteria->addCondition('add_min_qty ='.$this->add_max_qty );
```

Comment: ->addCondition allows all kinds of operations! Even <= and is not null ,

Comment: yes, but it gave me syntax error.

Comment: how about including the query that was trying to perform?

Comment: please mention syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Compare performs only equal match if you do not use extra parameter (true).

```
//$criteria->compare('t.id',$id,true);
```

True parameter is passed for %like% search.

For less than or greater than you can use condition. Try by changing your condition something like below

```
$criteria->condition = 'id>=:id'; //greater than equal
//or
//$criteria->condition = 'id<=:id'; // less than equal
$criteria->params = array(':id'=>$id);
```

It works fine for me. I hope it will solve your problems. :)